# Submit JQuery form with Enter Key in addition to submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have taken over development of a property sales website from another developer. Unfortunately I am not an expert on JQuery and there is a script that is causing me issues.

The script below allows users to look up price information for properties under a specific postcode. However the form will only submit when clicking on the 'submit button' and not when pressing the enter key. Please can anybody advise on a solution?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // $('#postcode_form').on('submit', function (e) 
    $('#postcode_form_submit').on('click', function (e) 


    
    {
          
          e.preventDefault();
          
          $('.emsg').addClass('hidden');
          $('.emsg').hide();
          // var postcodeRegEx = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}/i; 
          var postcodeRegEx = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Z]?\s?[0-9][A-Z]{2}/g; 
         
          if (!postcodeRegEx.test($("#postcode").val()))
          {
            // there is a mismatch, hence show the error message
            $('.emsg').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.emsg').show();
            return;
          }       
          
          $.ajax(
          {
            type: 'post',
            url: '/ajax_getresults.php',
            // url: '/get_properties/',
            data: $('#postcode_form').serialize(),
            data:{postcode:$("#postcode").val()},
            success: function (data,status) 
            {
              let result=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              if (result.status=="success")
              {               
                   $("#postcode_table").removeClass('hidden');
                   $("#postcode_table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                   // $("#postcode_table").empty();
                  let items=result.data;
                  $.each(items, function(index, value) 
                  {
                        //$("#servers").text($("#servers").text() + " " + value.servername);
                        $('#postcode_table').append("<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+value.house_no+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+value.street+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+value.sale_price+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+value.date+"</td>"+
                        +"</tr>");                      
                  });
              }
              else
              {
                  alert ("invalid results");
              }
            }
          });
    });

});
</script>
<div class="col-md-12">
<br/>
<hr/>
                            <div class="user_details_row">Please enter a Postcode to look up land registry sale history</div>
<div>
<form id="postcode_form" action="/get_properties/" method="post">
    <label for="property_label_before">
  Please enter postcode in capitals (e.g LS16 5BA):</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="" placeholder="LS16 5BA" size="40" style="max-width: 200px;display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<span class="emsg hidden" style="display: block; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;" >Please enter a valid postcode</span>
  <input id="postcode_form_submit" type="button" value="View historical sale price data" style="background-color: #0047ab; color: #fff; padding:15px;text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 700;">
</form>  
</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <br/>
          
            <table id="postcode_table" class="hidden" style="width:100%;text-align:left;">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
                            <th style="font-weight:bold;">HOUSE NO</th><th style="font-weight:bold;">STREET</th><th style="font-weight:bold;">SALE PRICE</th>
                            <th style="font-weight:bold;">DATE SOLD</th>
                    </tr>
                <thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like it was a conscious design decision to require the user to click submit as quite often new users (or elderly (sweeping generalisation ofc)) will press enter and submit the form half-way through.  So designers/developers remove this so it doesn't happen by accident.  Especially if the form has multi-line inputs where enter *doesn't* submit.  It can be confusing to have enter as submit.  You can always tab to the submit button and press space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is `$('#postcode_form').on('submit', function (e)` commented out? That's the right way to do it, you just need to change `<input id="postcode_form_submit" type="button"` to `<input id="postcode_form_submit" type="submit"`. If there is a submit button, browsers will submit on Enter.

Comment: Perfect, that's fixed it, I'd completely missed that! Many Thanks :)